# Delete rows in apply() function or depending on apply() result

Tags: python, pandas

Here I have a working solution but my question focus on how to do this the Pandas way. I assume Pandas over better solutions for this.

I use `groupby()` and then `apply(axis=1)` to compare the values in the rows of the groups. And while doing this I made the decision which row to delete.

*The rule doesn't matter!* In this example here the rule is that when values in column `A` differ only by `1` (the values are "near") then delete the second one. How the decision is made is not part of the question. There could also be a list of color names and I would say that `darkblue` and `marineblue` are "near" and one if should be deleted.

The initial data frame is that.

```
   X   A  B
0  A   9  0  <--- DELETE
1  A  14  1
2  A   8  2
3  A   1  3
4  A  18  4
5  B  10  5
6  B  20  6
7  B  11  7  <--- DELETE
8  B  30  8
```

Row index `0` should be deleted because it's value `9` is near the value `8` in row index `2`. The same with row index `7`: It's value `11` is "near" `10` in row index `5`.

That is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'X': list('AAAAABBBB'),
        'A': [9, 14, 8, 1, 18, 10, 20, 11, 30],
        'B': range(9)
    }
)
print(df)

def mark_near_neighbors(group):
    # I snip the decission process here.
    # Delete 9 because it is "near" 8.

    default_result = pd.Series(
        data=[False] * len(group),
        index=['Delete'] * len(group)
    )

    if group.X.iloc[0] is 'A':
        # the 9
        default_result.iloc[0] = True
    else:
        # the 11
        default_result.iloc[2] = True

    return default_result

result = df.groupby('X').apply(mark_near_neighbors)
result = result.reset_index(drop=True)
print(result)

df = df.loc[~result]
print(df)
```

So in the end I use a "boolean indexing thing" to solve this

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
dtype: bool
```

But is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([

    ['A', 9, 0],
    ['A', 14, 1],
    ['A', 8, 2],
    ['A', 1, 3],
    ['B', 18, 4],
    ['B', 10, 5],
    ['B', 20, 6],
    ['B', 11, 7],
    ['B', 30, 8],

], columns=['X', 'A', 'B'])
```

Sort the dataframe based on A column

```
df = df.sort_values('A')
```

Find the difference between values

```
df["diff" ] =df.groupby('X')['A'].diff()
```

Select the rows where the difference is not 1

```
result = df[df["diff"] != 1.0]
```

Drop the extra column and sort by index to get the initial dataframe

```
result.drop("diff", axis=1, inplace=True)
result = result.sort_index()
```

Sample output

```
    X   A   B
1   A   14  1
2   A   8   2
3   A   1   3
4   B   18  4
5   B   10  5
6   B   20  6
8   B   30  8
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use numpy broadcasting to compare all values within a group. Keeping everything with `apply` here as it seems wanted:

```
def mark_near_neighbors(group, thresh=1):
    a = group.to_numpy().astype(float)
    idx = np.argsort(a)
    b = a[idx]
    d = abs(b-b[:,None])
    d[np.triu_indices(d.shape[0])] = thresh+1
    return pd.Series((d>thresh).all(1)[np.argsort(idx)], index=group.index)

out = df[df.groupby('X')['A'].apply(mark_near_neighbors)]
```

output:

```
   X   A  B
1  A  14  1
2  A   8  2
3  A   1  3
4  A  18  4
5  B  10  5
6  B  20  6
8  B  30  8
```